# How to detect cycles in spark dataset

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I have a Spark dataset which contains the following data columns: BuyerID, SellerID . I need to find if there are cycles in these transactions. For example A sold B and B sold A. What is the best way to achieve this in Spark. There are some other columns in the dataset which I have not mentioned, to keep the question simple.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to find if there are cycles in these transactions. For example A sold B and B sold A.

With such informal definition of cycle (as opposed to a formal graph theory definition) it is almost trivial to implement this in Spark. Sort the labels:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val dfFromTo = df
  .withColumn("from", least($"BuyerID", $"SellerID"))
  .withColumn("to", greatest($"BuyerID", $"SellerID"))
```

Aggregate and filter:

```
val cycles = dfFromTo.groupBy("from", "to").count.where($"count" > 1)
```

Anti-join to remove cycles from the data:

```
dfFromTo.join(cycles, Seq("from", "to"), "leftanti")
```

Formal cycle detection (like A -> B -> C -> A) are technically speaking possible using graph processing primitives (like message passing), but typically don't scale well, unless you make very strict restrictions about the input.

In cases like this it is better to use optimized in-core tools (if possible), or dedicated graph processing tools (in opposition to abandoned [GraphX] or piggy-backing on top of SQL [graphframes] tools available in Spark).

Comment: Thanks for the response. The id column is not numeric in this case. It is alphanumeric.Also would appreciate a Java solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try the Self Join

```
val data = Seq((1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(2,1),(2,3)).toDF("Buyer","Seller")
 data.as("df1").join(data.as("df2"), $"df1.Buyer" === $"df2.Seller" and $"df1.Seller" === $"df2.Buyer")
```

Output

```
+-----+------+-----+------+
|Buyer|Seller|Buyer|Seller|
+-----+------+-----+------+
|    1|     2|    2|     1|
|    2|     1|    1|     2|
+-----+------+-----+------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you give a Java equivalent for this please.